# How to delete tombstones of cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

My OpsCenter give me 'Failed' result on Tombstone count performance service. I read [this paper](https://opencredo.com/cassandra-tombstones-common-issues/) and find that may be the insertion of `NULL` value is the casual.

So I try to fix this problem using the following procedures:

1. Set the `NULL` column of table `channels` and `articles` to ''. And for checking reason, there is no any insertings to these two tables.
2. Set `gc_grace_seconds` to `0` using commands:

   `alter table channels with gc_grace_seconds = 0
   alter table articles with gc_grace_seconds = 0`
3. Truncate `bestpractice_results` table in `OpsCenter` keyspace.
4. Restart agents and OpsCenter using commands:

   `service datastax-agent restart
   service opscenterd restart`

But, when OpsCenter run routine performance check (every 1 minute), the following 'Failed' information appeared again. And the number of tombstones is not changed (i.e., 23552 and 1374)

And I have the question:

1. How to remove these tombstones when there is no any insertion operations on two tables ?
   Do I need `repair` the cluster ?

[image]

OpsCenter Version: 6.0.3 Cassandra Version: 2.1.15.1423 DataStax Enterprise Version: 4.8.10

Comment: You also have to trigger a compaction for the tombstones to be pruned from your data files.

Comment: Thanks. I have triggered the compaction using command `nodetool -p portNumber compact keyspace channels`, but the number of tombstone still not changed. should I `reboot` the datastax ?

Comment: A reboot is certainly not required. You ran compaction on every node?

Comment: I following the [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsCompact.html) to run `compact` for table `channels`, I think `compact` is the concept for table. How to run compact for every node ?

Comment: You need to repeat the nodetool command for every node. Use `-h` to specify the hosts running your nodes.

Comment: Following the link said `Cassandra will fully drop those tombstones when a compaction triggers, only after local_delete_time + gc_grace_seconds as defined on the table the data belongs to. Remember that all the nodes are supposed to have been repaired within gc_grace_seconds to ensure a correct distribution of the tombstones and prevent deleted data from reappearing as mentioned above.` I first run `nodetool -h hosts repair` on every nodes, and then I run `nodetool -p portNumber compact` on every nodes, the tombstone will be disappeared, is the order right?

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick.

Comment: But I think I should set `gc_grace_seconds ` first, it seems that `0` is not a proper value since `all the nodes are supposed to have been repaired within gc_grace_seconds`, am I right ?

Comment: Setting `gc_grace_seconds = 0` is dangerous if you have more than one node as you risk deleted data to be resurrected in case your cluster gets partitioned due to network outages or single nodes are down and your keyspace is configured for data redundancy. But that was not your question. Your question was about how to rid yourself of tombstones immediately. And if you want to clear out all tombstones immediately, then setting `gc_grace_seconds = 0` is required.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please go through below link to get complete info about Delete and Tombstone.. It may be helpful for you. 
http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure about this sentence `Remember that all the nodes are supposed to have been repaired within gc_grace_seconds to ensure a correct distribution of the tombstones and prevent deleted data from reappearing as mentioned above.` What does `repair` mean ? It means `reboot` the cluster ?

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/tools/toolsRepair.html) for repairs: `./nodetool help repair`

Answer (score 10):

With Cassandra 3.10+, use

```
nodetool garbagecollect keyspace_name table_name
```

Check https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsGarbageCollect.html

Comment: Thanks very much! It helped in reclaiming the disk space.